# Сравнить текст src

Tags: javascript, аудио, ссылка

Как сравнить два текста src чтоб при втором нажатии на ссылку срабатывала пауза?

```
let myAudio = new Audio;

function playAudio(s){

if (myAudio)
    myAudio.pause();

myAudio = new Audio();
  if (s == 1 ){
      myAudio.src = "music/muladhara.mp3" ;
  } else if (s == 2){
      myAudio.src = "music/solemnGrace.mp3";
  }

myAudio.play()
}

<a onclick="playAudio(1);">Anjey Satori - Muladhara</a>
<a onclick="playAudio(2);">Musical Mandalas - Solemn Grace</a>
```

Я пробовала так:

```
if (myAudio.src == myAudio.src) {
myAudio.pause() }
```

Оно игнорирует myAudio.play() и музыка ставится на паузу еще до того как начнется проигрывание. Поэтому я думаю нужно сравнивать именно текст src. Как это сделать?

```
if (myAudio.paused == true) {
    myAudio.play();

} else {
    myAudio.pause();
}
```

Comment: `if (myAudio.src == myAudio.src) {` - прочитайте это еще раз. Не торопитесь. Подумайте.

Comment: XD да я понимаю что глупость написала

Answer (score 1):

у myAudio есть boolean свойство paused с помошю которого можно проверить играет или нет

```js
    let myAudio = new Audio()
    let arg = null
      function playAudio(s){
        if (!myAudio.paused){
          myAudio.pause();
          if(arg == s){
            return
          }
        }
        if(s == 1){
          myAudio.src = 'https://docs.google.com/uc?id=1UL2j-P2nEHS0pL8BtPechND7fp_fItdv';
        }
        if(s == 2){
          myAudio.src = 'https://docs.google.com/uc?id=1rLVk2-zzGCCeuGiLl_6gg3dEPxqpRPMR';
        }
        arg = s
        myAudio.play();
      }
```

```html
    <a onclick="playAudio(1);">music 1</a>
    <br>
    <a onclick="playAudio(2);">music 2</a>
```

Comment: почему-то всегда выдает true

Comment: в вопросе указала как пробовала